# Magento - adding product attributes to collections in xml

Tags: xml, magento, search

I would like to add some of our custom product attributes to the collection that is returned for search results via xml. We are using the full text search method. I have successfully added attributes to the sale quote items in a config.xml using:

```
<sales>
 <quote>
   <item>
      <product_attributes>
        <prod_grp_cd />
      </product_attributes>
   </item>
  </quote>
</sales>
```

Is it possible to do the same for the search results? The collection is Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection. I did a little digging and I see how quote item is doing it, but I don’t see that same code in the fulltext module. But hopefully I missed something or there is another way.

The end goal is to display these attributes on the search results page without having to override how the collection is created.

Answer (score 1):

Magento support had me check the attribute settings. The search results use a product list and one of the attribute settings is "Use in Product List". So any attributes you want to show up in a product list collection you just have to change that setting.